# create-or-extend-tables with Eclipselink does not work

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using Eclipselink 2.5.1 and I have the problem that no table update take place when I run Project->JPA Tools->Create tables form Entites... although I have

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
```

in my peristence.xml (with generation output mode = database).

I have an already existing database table *addresses* created from a JpaEntity *Address*. 
After table creation I wanted to add a further column named *addressType* which is of type *AddressType* which is an enum.

In my JpaEntity *Address* Eclipse is grumbling that *addressType* column can not be found in table *addresses*.

Re-running table creation from entities does not what I want. The column will not be added to the existing table structure. what am I missing to do?

Running Project->JPA Tools->Create tables from Entities... gives the following output:

```
[EL Config]: metadata: The alias name for the entity class [class com.tsystems.ikt.service.jpaParking.model.Address] is being defaulted to: Address.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [region] is being defaulted to: REGION.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [street] is being defaulted to: STREET.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [zipCode] is being defaulted to: ZIPCODE.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [streetNumber] is being defaulted to: STREETNUMBER.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [addressType] is being defaulted to: ADDRESSTYPE.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [addressId] is being defaulted to: ADDRESSID.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [city] is being defaulted to: CITY.
[EL Config]: metadata: The column name for element [country] is being defaulted to: COUNTRY.
[EL Info]: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5
[EL Fine]: connection: Detected database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1483721814)--DROP TABLE addresses
[EL Fine]: sql: SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception:        
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Error Code: 1217
Call: DROP TABLE addresses
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP TABLE addresses")

[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1483721814)--DROP TABLE entrances
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1483721814)--DROP TABLE addresses
[EL Fine]: sql: SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Error Code: 1217
Call: DROP TABLE addresses
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP TABLE addresses")
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1483721814)--DROP TABLE addresses
[EL Fine]: sql: SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception:     com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Error Code: 1217
Call: DROP TABLE addresses
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP TABLE addresses")
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1483721814)--DROP TABLE addresses
[EL Fine]: sql: SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -     2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception:     
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Error Code: 1217
Call: DROP TABLE addresses
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP TABLE addresses")
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1483721814)--DROP TABLE addresses
[EL Fine]: sql: SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

Internal Exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Error Code: 1217
Call: DROP TABLE addresses
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP TABLE addresses")
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1483721814)--CREATE TABLE addresses (ADDRESSID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, ADDRESSTYPE VARCHAR(50), CITY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, COUNTRY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, REGION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, STREET VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, STREETNUMBER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, ZIPCODE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ADDRESSID))
[EL Fine]: sql: SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -     2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'addresses' already exists
Error Code: 1050
Call: CREATE TABLE addresses (ADDRESSID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, ADDRESSTYPE VARCHAR(50), CITY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, COUNTRY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, REGION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, STREET VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, STREETNUMBER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, ZIPCODE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ADDRESSID))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE addresses (ADDRESSID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, ADDRESSTYPE VARCHAR(50), CITY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, COUNTRY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, REGION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, STREET VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, STREETNUMBER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, ZIPCODE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ADDRESSID))")
```

Why does Eclipselinkt try to drop and re-create the table *addresses* although I said *create-or-extend-tables*?

Comment: Any thoughts regarding the answer provided by @Chris May 15, 2014?

Answer (score 0):

"eclipselink.ddl-generation" is an EclipseLink runtime property that is looked at when you deploy your peristence unit, but you are not running/deploying your persistence unit.  Instead you are executing an Eclipse command to create tables from your entities. Eclipse uses EclipseLink under the covers, but will pass in its own properties to be sure your tables get created on the database it is pointed at.  This the settings are described here:
https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks007.htm

If you want to have EclipseLink extend your tables, just run your app.